# MySQL different integer datatype operation

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

There are different datatypes used to build a column in MySQL table. For example **SMALLINT**, **MEDIUMINT**, and **INT**. I understand that different datatype will affect table size according to column types. Therefore, its unnecessary to assign **UNSIGNED INT** to a value which ranges between 0-1000.

What happens if you multiply values of different datatypes in MySQL (e.g. **SMALLINT** * **INT**)? What MySQL datatype do you need to store the result?

Comment: hmm.. I concur that you should have consistent integer types throughout your column? What about arithmetic overflow?

Comment: Sorry I just answered my own question. I found the solution [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html). So, Should I discard this question? or write an answer it myself?

Comment: if you want you can answer your question or delete your question

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question you can post the answer. However I suggest you edit your question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL defines some rules for arithmetic operations.

- In case of `+`, `-`, `*` result is calculated to `BIGINT` (64-bit) precision if both operands are integers (e.g. `SMALLINT`, `INT`)
- If both operands are integer and any of them are `UNSIGNED`, the result is an unsigned integer. For subtraction (`-`) if `NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION` SQL mode is enabled, the result will be signed.
- If any of the operands of a `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `%` is real (e.g. `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`) or string value (e.g. `'10.13e-3'`) the precision of the result is the precision of the operand with the maximum precision.

It is safe to do arithmetic operations between columns with different datatypes. MySQL will automatically convert into appropriate format.

As for storing its result, there are some constraints.

- If out-of-range value is inserted, largest endpoint will be stored (e.g. inserting 130 to `TINYINT` will store 127 and raise warning). If strict mode is enabled, insertion will fail and raise error.
- Integer overflow results in silent wraparound (e.g. 9223372036854775807 + 1 = -9223372036854775808. This is because its the largest possible operation using `BIGINT` datatype).
- When a floating-point or fixed-point column is assigned a value that exceeds the range implied by the specified (or default) precision and scale, MySQL stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint of that range
- Floating-point overflow produces `NULL` result. Some operation can result in `+INF`, `-INF` or `NaN'.
- `DECIMAL` datatype, if overflowed, will be truncated. And raise warning.

References (from [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com)):

- [Out of range & Overflow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)
- [Arithmetic functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html)